# Count After A join relation in Pig

Tags: join, count, apache-pig

I am trying to load two files from hdfs to pig.
After I join Driver Relation with Truck Relation, I would like to count.
How can I count the rows in relation ? 
I tried this but it gives me count with group not a single count:

```
truck_temp = FOREACH (GROUP truck_join BY  drivers_info::driverId) { GENERATE  group, COUNT(truck_join); };
```

---

```
drivers_load = LOAD '/Pig-Practice/drivers.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (driverId:int,name:chararray,ssn:biginteger,location:chararray,certified:chararray,wageplan:chararray);
drivers_info = FOREACH ( GROUP drivers_load BY (driverId,name)) GENERATE group.driverId,group.name;

event_load = LOAD '/Pig-Practice/truck_event_text_partition.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (driverId:int, truckId:int, eventTime:chararray,
eventType:chararray, longitude:double, latitude:double,
eventKey:chararray, correlationId:long, driverName:chararray,
routeId:long,routeName:chararray,eventDate:chararray);
truck_events1 = FILTER event_load BY $0 >1;

truck_events2 =  FOREACH (GROUP truck_events1 BY (driverId,driverName,routeId,routeName) ) GENERATE group.driverId,group.driverName,group.routeId,group.routeName;

truck_join =  JOIN drivers_info BY driverId, truck_events2 BY driverId;
```

Comment: Hi Brian,  Thanks for the answer. This gives result as (10,1)
(11,4)
(12,4)
(13,5)
(14,5)
(15,4)
(16,4)
(17,1)
(18,1)
.... I need a single result like in SQL instead of multiple tuple. Select count(1) from truck_join

Answer (score 0):

For getting the total count after a join, you need to group all.

*COUNT requires a preceding GROUP ALL statement for global counts and a GROUP BY statement for group counts.*
Reference: [COUNT](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/func.html#count)

```
truck_temp = FOREACH (GROUP truck_join ALL) 
             { 
                 GENERATE  COUNT(truck_join); 
             };
```